# TypeORM index creation

Tags: typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

Is it possible to create an unique index with certain ascending/descending fields so that the outcome would be something like this?

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IDX_article_version_latest" ON "public"."article" ("uuid" ASC, "version" DESC, "updatedAt" DESC)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not supported yet. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3336).

The only workaround is to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/indices.md#disabling-synchronization):

*TypeORM does not support some index options and definitions because of a lot of different database specifics and multiple issues with getting information about exist database indices and synchronizing them automatically. In such cases you should create index manually (for example in the migrations) with any index signature you want. To make TypeORM ignore these indices during synchronization use `synchronize: false` option on `@Index` decorator.*

In the Article class add the `@Index` decorator and disable *synchronization* to avoid deletion on the next schema sync:

```js
@Index("IDX_article_version_latest", { synchronize: false })
/* ...*/
class Article { /*...*/ }
```

Create the [Migration](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md):

```js
export class IndexArticleVersionLatest implements MigrationInterface {
    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IDX_article_version_latest" ON "public"."article" ("uuid" ASC, "version" DESC, "updatedAt" DESC)`);
    }

    async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "IDX_article_version_latest"`);
    }
}
```

Remember to register the migration(s) in the TypeORM configuration. Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md)